# Readonly property not working in IE9 when masking is applied

Tags: javascript, jsp, internet-explorer, masking

Masked Phone number text field becomes editable even though its applied with readonly property.

How to solve this issue. It happens only in IE9 browser.

```
 $("#stdphone").attr('readonly', true)
```

Comment: can you post how you set readonly?

Comment: $("stdphone").attr('readonly', true)

Comment: What is the plugin you are used for masking? post few more lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

try this if its working in IE9:

```
$("#stdphone").attr('readonly', 'readonly');
```

Comment: actualy i have tried that too, but doesnt work. Of all the fields in form, this is the only field thats giving this issue. i guess it could be cause of masking.

Comment: OOps ,sorry @PraveenNagarajan, IE is so grrr. why not set it on html ? readonly = readonly? haha

Comment: Its a editable field and i make it readonly under certain business rules. So thats where i get the problem.